# ULS Logs in sharepoint 2007

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, logging, sharepoint-2007

Is there a way to get ULS Logs from all servers in a farm in wss or moss. I need to obtain logs programmatically using C#. I can get logs from one server in a farm, but I need all of them. Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/1acfe853-5da7-4a4e-9097-d99b6dfd3b79 I've read this article, but it also didn't work for me. Any ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the ULS Viewer:  http://ulsviewer.codeplex.com/

Or you could write your own logging service using `SPDiagnosticsService`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg512103.aspx

Edit from the comments:

To read files directly you could do:

```
   try 
    {
        // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
        // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("FilePath:\\SharePointlogfile.uls")) 
        {
            string line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
            // the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // Let the user know what went wrong.
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

Comment: the thing is that I need get logs programmatically, without tools. And for wss 2007.

Comment: Your best bet IMO is to Use the SPDiagnosticsService class and apply to a Farm Level.  If your program can access all the servers in the farm you could read the files directly by using a simple StreamReader and pointing it at {SharePoint Root}\LOGS for each server.

Comment: I can access all the servers, but cold you provide line of code. I have no idea how to read files directly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Alexander set it in the code or you could have a List<string> called filePaths that contains all of your file paths.

Comment: the main problem for me how to obtain filePaths using SPDiagnosticsService class. I believe that this will solve my problem. Now I am trying to solve my need by power-shell command Merge-SPLogFile